# LUIS score getting re aligned on dispatch refresh

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have 3 Luis models and I'm using Dispatch Luis model for routing between them. Each time, I call the dispatch refresh command from CLI, the dispatch model gets re-created and the confidence scores for different intents become realigned. Due to this, some of the user queries that worked perfectly earlier fails.
The dispatch model isn't checking for confidence scores in each of the children Luis

Routing without Dispatch in code by comparing confidence scores from each child Luis, works fine.

Tha case when there are overlapping utterances in LUIS and QNA is mentioned here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#resolving-incorrect-top-intent-from-dispatch
But in this case ,the overlapping utterances are between 2 Luis models.

I expected the dispatch to route based on the confidence scores of the individual Luis models. Each time its refreshed, there is an element of unpredictability. Is this the expected behavior or am I missing out something here?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using? Just `dispatch refresh`? And you are seeing the confidence scores change in the LUIS portal under `build`?

Comment: Yes, just "dispatch refresh". The child Luis scores remain the same. But the dispatch routes the utterance to the wrong luis.

Comment: My assumption is that you are making changes to the LUIS models (or is there another reason you are running refresh?). If you query through the Test Panel in the LUIS portal, does the same behavior (wrong intent) happen there? How do you have your none intents set up? Did you remove all but the main dispatcher none intent (as per the linked article above) or go another route? is the none intent well trained?

Comment: Yes, I had to add more intents to the child LUIS models. That's the reason I am calling dispatch refresh. In the test panel of dispatch, its the same behavior. I have removed all the None intents from child LUIS models.

Comment: I think there is two things we can try at this point. You can try [training with all data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-train#train-with-all-data). Alternatively, I can see if I can reproduce the issue and work out what is going on. I would need models, and changes to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you try training with all data? Do you still need help?